# VS2005 freeze and disk thrashing when opening designers in C# projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

In *some* projects, but not all, when I open a designer for the first time (either WinForms or typed dataset) Visual Studio thrashes the disk for up to 30 minutes while freezing (this appears to be reads and writes with between 100 and 140 pages\sec).
Once it has done it the first time for a project, it's fine opening other projects until I close and re-open VS where it will freeze/thrash again the first time I open a designer.

Does anyone else see this, what the hell is it doing, and is there anything I can do to stop it?

Comment: I have problems too, but not to that extent (normally 2-3 mins every couple of hours).
The biggest problem I have is related to the network, not sure why, but as I work locally when developing. If I get in early, it works like a charm.
 The other problem is the virus checker, I had to put exclusions in on the file type.
Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Nothing definite (hence I haven't posted as an answer), but you could try enabling compression for your code and/or VS folders... if disk IO is being *that* disruptive, maybe burn some CPU instead?

Comment: Possibly you need to defragment your disk? Definitely you need to find out what's going on, and not just blame Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, the disk is defragged (pagefile was fine, but PerfectDisk reported that the 'metadata' was fragemented), and this issue is still there.

I can't see why all this disk thrashing is required to open a designer for a dataset with a single table and two adapters ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it looks like it was defunct database connections in the Server Explorer tab:

A database on our test server was removed without my knowledge, but my project still had a data connection set up for it. It seems that whenever a table adapter is initialised in the designer, VS tries to connect to all the databases in the data connections list causing issues if the database does not exist. It even tries to connect to data connections that are not used by the current table adapter.

Some of our WinForms were badly written (naughy devs!) and were loading data in the constructors without checking for 'DesignMode' - these have been repaired.

Herbie

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are either running short on RAM and opening a designer puts it over the top or your hard disk needs to be defragmented.

It could be registry fragmentation too. Try [pagedefrag](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897426.aspx).

Comment: As I mentioned above, my disk is in good condition (I defrag fairly regularly).
My machine has 3Gb, and the system appears to report 1.5Gb free (although I think I'll find another utility to verify this).

So it doesn't appear to be either of these two things.

Herbie

Comment: Ok, I can verify that throughout the entire process a minimum of 1Gb of free memory is available.  Free memory drops by about 40Mb while the disk is being thrashed, but rises again at the end.

So it's not that I'm short of memory or that my HDD is defragmented.